# Possibility to write code without include <string.h>

Tags: c

I have written a code that defines a function with signature and takes 2 parameters C, it returns a number from 0 of 1st parameter - If the 2nd parameter contains the 1st parameter or - 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int str_find(char* needle, char* haystack) {
    int needle_length = strlen(needle);
    int haystack_length = strlen(haystack);

    if (needle_length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (haystack_length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int par_1 = 0;

    for(int par_2 = 0; par_2 < haystack_length; par_2++) {
        if (haystack[par_2] == needle[0]) {
            for (par_1 = 0; par_1 < needle_length; par_1++)
                if (haystack[par_2 + par_1])
                    break;
            if (par_2 == needle_length)
                return par_2;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",str_find("=","-h=123"));
    return 0;
}
```

Would it be possible/How to write this code without using the `<string.h>` library?

Comment: Please remove the double-spacing from the code snippet. It makes it harder to read.

Comment: A `strlen()` function is all you need. Aside: it returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: Hint to reproduce `strlen()`: how do you know when you reached the end of a string (array of char)?

Comment: @mikyll98 wasn't it marked with the null character?

Comment: @onix012 you're almost there: that's right, but how do you represent that in C?

Comment: yes -- BUT WHY WOULD YOU?  Using libraries that are well tested and work is good programming -- why wouldn't you want to do so?

Comment: @Hogan I think it's quite obvious that's not the point: he's probably attending a C programming course, and is learning about `char` arrays, he'll sure learn to use the proper tools when he gets to a more advanced level :) (I'm saying so because I had the exact same exercises)

Comment: "without the most obvious library" is a typical teacher/assignment thing. Just in case this happens to be a homework, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @mikyll98 You put \0 at the end of the function?

Comment: If you only want to avoid to include string.h you can simply declare the function `strlen()` yourself, and use it exactly as before. That is totally possible.

Comment: Why introduce the strlen concept by force? This can be achieved by comparing while neither is 0.

Comment: @onix012 not quite right, but you got the "terminator character" `\0`: what `strlen()` does is it iterates over the array elements and increments a counter, until it reaches the terminator. Try to figure out how to implement that

Comment: @mikyll98 -- don't have to write strlen() to do this.

Comment: @Hogan to do what? To learn `char` arrays in C? Surely not, but in my opinion it's a good starting point :) also learning to code becomes much more fun and interesting when you get to solutions understanding what happens

Comment: @mikyll98 -- I think you learn more about strings in C by knowing how to check for a string of length zero without strlen() ~ as an example.

Comment: In fact, at least in legacy C you don't even need a declaration -- not sure about newer standards. In any case, a current gcc accepts the following program: `int main()
{
        return strlen("123");
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the haystack is a few Gb, why traverse it simply to determine the upper bound? Traverse the haystack only once (or less)...

Little challenges are a good chance to play with code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int str_find( char* needle, char* haystack) {
    size_t i = 0, matched = 0;

    while( haystack[ i ] && needle[matched] )
        if( needle[ matched ] == haystack[i] )
            matched++, i++;
        else if( matched )
            i -= matched - 1, matched = 0; // rewind a bit and try again
        else i++;

    return needle[matched] == '\0' ? i - matched : -1;
}

int main() {

    char *hay = "longlongagoinagalaxyfarfarawaygeorgelucasmadeababananana";

    char *needles[] = { "far", "lucas", "yoda", "force", "banana" };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof needles/sizeof needles[0]; i++ )
        printf( "%s - %sfound\n", needles[i], str_find( needles[i], hay ) < 0 ? "not " : "" );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
far - found
lucas - found
yoda - not found
force - not found
banana - found
```

EDIT:

In fact, rather than simply found/not-found, this challenge suggests finding multiple instances of any needle (or not finding any) so is worthy of more development.

Here, the return from `str_find()` is put to more use and the testing done by `main()` made a bit more elaborate.

This code does not prevent searching for a zero length needle. If someone can describe what a zero-length needle looks like, I would appreciate reading about it in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_find( char *needle, char *haystack ) {
    size_t i = 0, matched = 0;

    while( needle[ matched ] && haystack[ i ] )
        if( needle[ matched ] == haystack[i] )
            matched++, i++;
        else if( matched )
            i -= matched - 1, matched = 0; // rewind a bit and try again
        else i++;

    return needle[ matched ] ? NULL : haystack + i - matched;
}

int main() {

    char *hay = "longlongagoinagalaxyfarfarawaygeorgelucasmadeababananana";

    char *needles[] = { "long", "far", "lucas", "yoda", "force", "banana", "nananana" };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof needles/sizeof needles[0]; i++ ) {
        printf( "%s:\n", needles[i] );
        size_t count = 0;
        for( char *p = hay; ( p = str_find( needles[i], p ) ) != NULL; p++ )
            printf( "\t#%d '%-.10s'\n", ++count, p );

        printf( "%d instances\n", count );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output showing the 'needle' and a few more characters of "context" following the needle.

```
long:
        #1 'longlongag'
        #2 'longagoina'
2 instances
far:
        #1 'farfaraway'
        #2 'farawaygeo'
2 instances
lucas:
        #1 'lucasmadea'
1 instances
yoda:
0 instances
force:
0 instances
banana:
        #1 'bananana'
1 instances
nananana:
0 instances
```

Comment: UV for nice minimal algorithm (Although not a  fan of `{}`-less and `,`).  Try compiling with `const char *hay = longlong";`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you... `:-)` I like (and have grown used-to) the brevity of using `,`. Makes things more compact, and _easier_ (imho) to glance and decide that "this does what it should do" (Admitting I make a LOT of oversights that my friends help uncover!) Re: const... Generous use of const in all the `char *` declarations (even `const char *str_find(...`) and this compiles/runs as intended. Again, thank you. `:-)`

Comment: Usually the return should still be `char *` in C.  Review `strchr();` in [C](https://www.javatpoint.com/strchr-function-in-c) vs. C++ with its [overloads](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The 'C' link you sent is... questionable. Code sample does not check return value from `scanf( )`... `:-)` Readers/users of above are free to add and/or "cast away const-ness in function" should they choose. I chose to avoid the issue altogether to focus on the little "mill" that is search for needle(s) in a haystack... All good! `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You could re-write this function to not use strlen.  First you use the results to see if the strings are 0 length, but you can do that by just checking if the first character is 0.

Later you use the length to check the ending of your for loop.  Once again you could just check the string at that point to see if it is 0.

In this way you would not have to use the string library.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible/How to write this code without using the <string.h> library?

Yes, it is possible.

---

Current code has problems/weaknesses:

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

For big strings, the length may exceed `int`.  Function goal does want to rerun a -1 under some cases, Better to use a signed integer that encompasses at least 1/2 the `size_t` range like `long` or `long long` or best: `ptrdiff_t` from `<stddef.h>`.

**`const`**

As the strings are not modified, use `const char *` parameters to allow for wider use.

**Doubtful functionality**

`if (haystack[par_2 + par_1]) break;` simple breaks the loop if not the *null character*.  No matching done.

**Efficiency**

OP's code appears to use a `O(needle_length*haystack_length)` approach.  `O(needle_length + haystack_length)` algorithms exist.

`int haystack_length = strlen(haystack);` not really needed to traverse the entire `haystack` before the real searching gets started.

Consider testing for the null character instead.

```
// for(int par_2 = 0; par_2 < haystack_length; par_2++) 
for(int par_2 = 0; haystack[par_2]; par_2++)
```

`int needle_length = strlen(needle);` not needed either.  Stop comparing when `needle[par_1] == 0`

---

**Consider**

```
// int str_find( char* needle, char* haystack) 
ptrdiff_t str_find(const char* needle, const char* haystack)
```

---

At least code has good parameter names `str_find(char* needle, char* haystack)`.